# Some devcontainer images don't work in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I have a devcontainer working in VSCode, but I can't get the same image to work with an IntelliJ IDE. I tried checking the [system requirements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prerequisites.html#min_requirements), and I think the image meets them. Are there other things needed in an image to be used as a devcontainer in IntelliJ?

I've tried in both PyCharm 2023.2.1 Pro and IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 Ultimate. I'm trying to use the `mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:2-linux` image, because it doesn't count as storage space in GitHub codespaces. When I try it with the `openjdk:11` image, it works.

Here's the display when I try to create a dev container:

```
Deploying 'Dev Container'…
Creating container…
Container Id: 137057385eae5fd7eeb5fa53f3c47248f481a9095ad8ad31d840adb78a92dd1f
Container name: '/suspicious_galileo'
Starting container '/suspicious_galileo'
'Dev Container' has been deployed successfully.
Preparing environment...
Environment is successfully prepared...
Status 409: {"message":"Container 137057385eae5fd7eeb5fa53f3c47248f481a9095ad8ad31d840adb78a92dd1f is not running"}
```

Here's the full `devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "udjango",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:2-linux"
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a Docker container using the image you mentioned. Does it start correctly? If so, please try to create an image using the following Dockerfile and check if it works:

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:2-linux`

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget unzip tar gzip`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that the GitHub default image has this weird entrypoint:

```
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/local/share/docker-init.sh",
                "/usr/local/share/ssh-init.sh"
            ]
```

If I override the entrypoint in my own Dockerfile, then it seems to work in VSCode, GitHub codespaces, and IntelliJ IDEs.

Here's the full `devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "udjango",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "postCreateCommand": ["pipenv", "install"],
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {
                "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash (2)",
                "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
                    "bash (2)": {
                        "path": "/home/codespace/.python/current/bin/pipenv-shell"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the full `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:2-linux

RUN python -m pip install pipenv && \
    printf "export PIPENV_SHELL=bash\npipenv shell" >/home/codespace/.python/current/bin/pipenv-shell && \
    chmod +x /home/codespace/.python/current/bin/pipenv-shell

ENTRYPOINT bash
```